# 4% of people was/were

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What is grammatically correct:

> saying “4% of people was classified as introverts”.

Or saying

> 4% of people were identified as introverts.

The context is that I’m reporting the results of a survey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the noun that follows **a percentage of** is plural, use a plural verb after it:

> e.g. 45% of people **are**(NOT is) interested in politics.
>
> e.g. Just 50% of U.S. adults now **get** (NOT gets) news regularly from television, down from 57% a year prior in early 2016.

And about your own example:

> 4% of people **were** (NOT was) identified as introverts.